# Calculating the Amount of Time for the Precession of the Equinoxes

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

OK, so in the process of building a world for my D&D campaign, I have gotten very into the science of world building.  Where I have gotten hung up is I want to have a realistic length of time for my precession of the equinoxes.  There are five major planets orbiting a binary star system and the planet I am concerned with has two moons.  How exactly would I calculate how long it takes for a full precession of the equinoxes?

Answer (score 2):

The [link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/146349/how-to-calculate-rate-of-axial-precession) mentioned in the comments has an excellent article and links for the complex calculations to figure this out (though it appears to me that it only allows for one significant moon).

More specifically, however, something many worldbuilders miss is that the Earth is not "typical" in many of its astronomical features: its rotation rate, axial tilt and precession are all abnormal for a planet of its size and orbit in relation to the Sun.

For instance, if you click this link you can see the [precession of the equinoxes for the Earth and other planets in the solar system](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/what-are-the-time-periods-of-precession-of-equinoxes-of-other-planets).  What you can notice is that the Earth does not follow the same pattern as the other planets, because the the precession period should be going up the farther it is from the sun(*).  So by that pattern the Earth should have a precession rate of about once every 90,000 years, but instead it's actually once every 25,600 which is faster than Venus's!

Additionally our rotation speed of once every 24 hours is extremely high for a planet of our mass so close to the sun 4 billion years after its creation. Normally we would expect the Earth to long ago have been tidally locked to the Sun or nearly so like Venus.  Even odder, we have a higher axial tilt than is thought to be typical(*) especially considering our rotation speed and closeness to the sun.

So why is this?  Well basically it's our moon which is so large compared to the Earth that it could be considered a binary planet system.  Together the Earth-Moon system is unlike anything else in our Solar System, causing all of these abnormalities.  The Moon provides a very disruptive tidal influence on the Earth cancelling out (and even overpowering) the monotonic tidal influence of the Sun alone. (**)

The upshot of all of this is that to get the rotational behaviors that you want you are probably going to have to have at least one large moon and carefully consider its characteristics.  You could have two large moons, but that greatly increases the difficulty of figuring out all of this, so it's probably better to have one large and one small moon.

(* and yes, Uranus is even odder than the Earth in this regard, for different, though uncertain reasons)

(** You might wonder why then is the Moon tidally locked to the Earth? It is believed that the Moon has a very asymmetrical distribution of mass internally that causes this)